# Parallel.for loop Execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops, parallel-processing

**Scenario**

I need to create `n` threads (*not equal* to number of function to executes) that execute multiple functions parallel. So my code is

```
    static void Main() 
    { 
        Parallel.For(0, 2, i => // it creates 2 threads as number of iterations.why?
            {
                  method1();
                  method2();
                  method3();
                  method4();
                  method5();
                  method6();
                  method7();
                  method8();
                  method9();
                  method10();
            });
     }
```

How to use `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` property here in best way? Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wish

```
var methods = new Action[] {
    method1, method2, method3, method4, method5, method6, method7, method8, method9, method10 };

Parallel.For(0, methods.Length, i =>
{
    methods[i]();
});
```

This way you can set the degree of parallelization

```
var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 };

Parallel.For(0, methods.Length, options, i =>
```

---

When you wrote `Parallel.For(0, 2`, it creates a loop for the specified number of elements: from 0 (inclusive) to 2 (exclusive). Therefore, there can be a maximum of two threads.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking for [Parallel.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke?view=netcore-3.1) instead of `Parallel.For` (I can't see any *loop* in your code):

```
  ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions() {
    //TODO: carry out experiment on your workstation to find out the right number
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4, 
  };

  // Run method1..method10 in parallel while using options 
  Parallel.Invoke(options,
    method1,
    method2,
    method3,
    method4,
    method5,
    method6,
    method7,
    method8,
    method9,
    method10
  );
```